# Kafka Connector: S3OutputStream can not be cast to S3ParquetOutputStream

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am building a Kafka connector for S3 where I want to store output as parquet files. I know there is already a Confluent connector doing it but we need an avro registry. This is something we do not want to create. That's why I modified the [source code](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/blob/master/kafka-connect-s3/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/s3/format/parquet/ParquetRecordWriterProvider.java) where i modified line 70 to give directly a custom avro schema built in another class.

However, when I run my custom kafka connector I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3OutputStream cannot be cast to io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3ParquetOutputStream
```

This error happens at the line 130 of the source code and this part is not modified in our code.

I really don't understand why I get this error and how I can solve.

Any idea would be very appreaciated.

Thanks